# How to name a person from the same country as speaker?

Tags: meaning, synonyms, vocabulary, translation, transatlantic-differences

My Slavic language (Slovak) uses the word *krajan*, speaker can in this way name another person whose origin lies in the same country/land/area/region.

English translations I have found:

- [compatriot](http://www.wordreference.com/definition/compatriot)
- [(fellow) countryman](http://www.wordreference.com/definition/countryman)
- [homeboy](http://www.wordreference.com/definition/homeboy)

I realize I could use all of them, but still what are **slight differences**, and, more importantly, which one is **more common**? I would like to know also about **UK and US difference**.

Feel free to include also **alternative vocabulary**.

Comment: 'homeboy' is very informal and is more for someone you know very well rather than just some arbitrary person with your same nationality.

Comment: In UK the first two are good, but not "homeboy" which reads like someone who stays at home to watch TV, sleep, wait for meals to be provided, etc.

Comment: @WeatherVane 'homeboy' is nothing like that. It is informal slang from AAE  that means (in its most literal sense) someone who I grew up with, friend from my neighborhood where I grew up. Usually though it just means my good friend (wherever they grew up).

Comment: @Mitch I wrote: **in UK**. We don't use the word "homeboy", but it might suggest what I wrote. OP asks about differences.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compatriot is naturally the word to express this situation. It fits the definition precisely, and is self-explanatory, refers to male and female citizens, and is identical in US and UK English.

Fellow countrymen/women is used frequently in articles due to it being a compound word (fellow+countrymen). Each word is fairly common and simple to understand, making the entire phrase easier to understand, but more of a mouthful. Usage is identical in US and UK English.

Homeboy is US mainly slang for being part of the same gang/social background. It is not frequently used, and rather informal and geographically more restrained.

Comment: Friends, Romans, compatriots.... :)

Comment: There is no way to name a person "from the same country as speaker"; not in English. That might be possible in another language you care to name but in English, never.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is "fellow ".

Can be used for countries, cities, regions, etc.

As in:

"fellow Canadian", "fellow Spaniard", or "fellow New Yorker".